# Removing blankspace at the start of a line (size of blankspace is not constant)

Tags: bash, csv, sed, uniq

I am a beginner to using `sed`. I am trying to use it to edit down a `uniq -c` result to remove the spaces before the numbers so that I can then convert it to a usable `.tsv`.

The furthest I have gotten is to use:

```
$ sed 's|\([0-9].*$\)|\1|' comp-c.csv
```

With the input:

```
     8 Delayed speech and language development
    15 Developmental Delay and additional significant developmental and morphological phenotypes referred for genetic testing
     4 Developmental delay AND/OR other significant developmental or morphological phenotypes
     1 Diaphragmatic eventration
     3 Downslanted palpebral fissures
```

The output from this is identical to the input; it recognises (I have tested it with a simple substitute) the first number but also drags in the prior blankspace for some reason.

To clarify, I would like to remove all spaces before the numbers; hardcoding a simple trimming will not work as some lines contain double/triple digit numbers and so do not have the same amount of blankspace before the number.

Bonus points for some way to produce a usable `uniq -c` result without this faffing around with blank space.

Comment: `s|\([0-9].*$\)|\1|` says `find the string from the first digit to the end of the line ([0-9].*$) and replace it with itself (\1)` which is why your output is identical to your input - it's not changing anything. I'd guess you were probably trying to write `s|^[^0-9]*\([0-9].*$\)|\1|` but [@janos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46695051/1745001) makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about writing the correct regex:

```
sed 's/^ *//' comp-c.csv
```

That is, *replace zero or more spaces at the start of lines* (as many as there are) with *nothing*.

> Bonus points for some way to produce a usable `uniq -c` result without this faffing around with blank space.

The `uniq` command doesn't have a flag to print its output without the leading blanks. There's no other way than to strip it yourself.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much.

Anyone looking for a usable _uniq -c_ result can use:

'sort -c $FILE | uniq -c | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e  's/ /[ ^I]/' > "$FILE".tsv'
where [ ^I] = TAB.